# How to generate oracle rank and dense_rank function in Talend?

Tags: oracle, etl, talend

SQL>  select ID,rank() over(order by ID) RANK , dense_rank() over(order by ID) DENSE_RANK from a;

```
ID    RANK    DENSE_RANK  
1       1       1  
1       1       1  
2       3       2  
3       4       3  
3       4       3  
4       6       4  
5       7       5  
5       7       5  
6       9       6   
7      10       7
```

Comment: What have you tried sofar?

Comment: So you get a dense rank by getting a rank on the distinct IDs that you join back with the main table.